# Ruby count number of found keywords in string

Tags: ruby

I have an array with keywords and I have a string, which may contain those keywords. I now need to know how many keywords are in the given string:

```
keywords = [ 'text' ,'keywords' ,'contains' ,'blue', '42']
text = 'This text is not long but it contains 3 keywords'
```

How can I now find out with a ruby command how many of the strings in my array are in the text (three in this case)? I could of course use a for each loop but I am almost sure that there is a more concise way to achieve this.

Thanks for your help

**Update**: Preferably the solution should not rely on the spaces. So the spaces could be replaced by arbitrary characters.

**Update 2**: The command should look for unique occurrences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
text.scan(/#{keywords.join('|')}/).length
```

Note that this is safe only if the *keywords* array contains only alphanumeric characters.

Comment: I'll add, you didn't mention whether you want only how many keywords appear at least once, or the total number of keywords in the string. You can get the former by calling _.uniq.length_ after the scan.

Comment: I think there's a safe way to escape any text so it can be turned into a regular expression.

Comment: @Andrew: In my case the keywords don't need to be escaped since they are only strings, but good call!

Comment: I was thinking of [Regexp.escape](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Regexp.html#method-c-escape), but you may as well do `Regexp.union(keywords)`.

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly what you wanted but

```
irb(main):012:0> text.split(' ')
=> ["This", "text", "is", "not", "long", "but", "it", "contains", "3", "keywords"]
irb(main):013:0> text.split(' ') & keywords
=> ["text", "contains", "keywords"]
```

will give you an array with matches

Comment: The text should also work for strings that do not contain spaces. However +1 from me since I did not initially state this requirement. :)

Comment: Just change the parameter to split and it works again, right?